# Recursive mixin in Pug

Tags: javascript, pug, mixins

We use Pug to produce a style guide, and have a mixin to generate a header and description for reusable elements. A simplified example is this:

```
mixin sgitem(name)
    if !isnested
        - isnested = true
        h3=name
        block
    else
        block
    - isnested = false
```

That means that if I write this:

```
+sgitem('Foo')
    include partial with sgitem
+sgitem('Baz')
    div Example here
```

, the nested item should just return the block and not the name. Well, that works, but not if there's a second or third nested sgitem:

```
+sgitem('Foo')
    include partial with sgitem
    include partial with sgitem
+sgitem('Baz')
    div Example here
```

That will generate this:

```
<h3>Foo</h3>
<div>Nested example</div>
<h3>Nested title</h3>
<div>Nested example</div>
<h3>Baz</h3>
<div>Example here</div>
```

, while I would like this:

```
<h3>Foo</h3>
<div>Nested example</div>
<div>Nested example</div>
<h3>Baz</h3>
<div>Example here</div>
```

It probably is an issue not with Pug per se, but with setting variables and so on. So how can a mixin correctly know if it is nested or not?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like what you're trying to do is overly complicated. Could you not just create something like the following?

```
mixin sgitem(title, description)
  if title
    h3=title
  if description
    div=description
```

Then call the mixins:

```
+sgitem('Foo', 'Nested example')
+sgitem('', 'Nested example')
+sgitem('Baz', 'Example here')
```

Which will render into:

```
<h3>Foo</h3>
<div>Nested example</div>
<div>Nested example</div>
<h3>Baz</h3>
<div>Example here</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to be able to nest them through includes. The styleguide items are based on atomic design, so the smallest items (with name and description) can be included in larger ones. But in that case only the block should be included.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up splitting the mixin from its content, and including each of that content when needed.

```
Partial file A:
li List item example here
```

and

```
Page with atoms:
+sgmixin('A list item', 'Bla bla')
    include atoms/A


Page with molecules:
+sgmixin('A list', 'Bla bla')
    ul
        include atoms/A
```